# Scaled Metric not working on Apple Watch?

Tags: swiftui, apple-watch

I'm trying to do this targeting Apple Watch:

```
    @ScaledMetric var widthScale: CGFloat = 1
```

and then apply the widthScale to the frame of some SwiftUI View elements:

```
    .frame(width: myFrame.width * widthScale, height: myHeight)
```

Only it doesn't change at all. Font Sizes do change all around but the widthScale always stays @ 1.0.

Did I get the idea wrong? Did I find a bug? Is it not supposed to be used on WatchOS?

Comment: It seems taking 1 as a factor is not a good idea. With sizeCategory "extraExtraExtraLarge" 1 scales to 1, 10 scales to 11.0 and 100 scales to 112. So I'm figuring they are using an Int Scale internally and not publicising the fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I found out by trial and error:

1. The @ScaledMetric should be defined inside the View it is applied in, not in a struct Type somewhere else.
2. @ScaledMetric values are rounded to whole pixels. So depending on the display density x2 or x3 it's rounded to 1/2halfs or 1/3rds.
   Use this view and the previews to see the different scales in action:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ScaledMetricText: View {
    @ScaledMetric(relativeTo: .caption) var widthScaleHundred: CGFloat = 100.0
    @ScaledMetric(relativeTo: .caption) var widthScaleTen: CGFloat = 10.0
    @ScaledMetric(relativeTo: .caption) var widthScaleOne: CGFloat = 1.0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Unscaled")
                .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
                .frame(width: 100)
                .background(Color(.lightGray))
                .padding(3)
            Text("100 -> \(widthScaleHundred)")
                .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
                .frame(width: 100 * widthScaleHundred / 100)
                .background(Color(.lightGray))
            Text("10 -> \(widthScaleTen)")
                .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
                .frame(width: 100 * widthScaleTen / 10)
                .background(Color(.lightGray))
                .padding(3)
            Text("1 -> \(widthScaleOne)")
                .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
                .frame(width: 100 * widthScaleOne)
                .background(Color(.lightGray))
        }
        .font(.caption)
    }
}

struct ScaledMetricText_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ScaledMetricText()
            .previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: "Apple Watch Series 6 - 40mm"))
            .environment(\.sizeCategory, ContentSizeCategory.small)
        ScaledMetricText()
            .previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: "Apple Watch Series 3 - 38mm"))
            .environment(\.sizeCategory, ContentSizeCategory.extraExtraExtraLarge)
        ScaledMetricText()
            .previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: "Apple Watch Series 6 - 44mm"))
            .environment(\.sizeCategory, ContentSizeCategory.small)
        ScaledMetricText()
            .previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: "Apple Watch Series 3 - 42mm"))
            .environment(\.sizeCategory, ContentSizeCategory.extraExtraExtraLarge)

    }
}
```

Or iOS Previews:

```
struct ScaledMetricText_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ScaledMetricText()
            .previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: "iPhone 8"))
            .environment(\.sizeCategory, ContentSizeCategory.small)
        ScaledMetricText()
            .previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: "iPhone 8"))
            .environment(\.sizeCategory, ContentSizeCategory.extraExtraExtraLarge)
        ScaledMetricText()
            .previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: "iPhone 12 Pro Max"))
            .environment(\.sizeCategory, ContentSizeCategory.small)
        ScaledMetricText()
            .previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: "iPhone 12 Pro Max"))
            .environment(\.sizeCategory, ContentSizeCategory.extraExtraExtraLarge)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the code below found that it does work. In principle, in Simulator and on my Watch. Still have to figure out why the problem above won't work.

```
struct TextLabelsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            DynamicResizingView()
        }
    }
}

struct DynamicResizingView: View {
    @ScaledMetric(relativeTo: .largeTitle) var scaledLargeTitle: CGFloat = 10
    @ScaledMetric(relativeTo: .title) var scaledTitle: CGFloat = 10
    @ScaledMetric(relativeTo: .headline) var scaledHeadline: CGFloat = 10
    @ScaledMetric(relativeTo: .subheadline) var scaledSubheadline: CGFloat = 10
    @ScaledMetric(relativeTo: .body) var scaledBody: CGFloat = 10
    @ScaledMetric(relativeTo: .callout) var scaledCallout: CGFloat = 10
    @ScaledMetric(relativeTo: .caption) var scaledCaption: CGFloat = 10
    @ScaledMetric(relativeTo: .footnote) var scaledFootnote: CGFloat = 10
    @ScaledMetric() var scaledNothing: CGFloat = 10

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Dynamic Base10").font(Font.system(size:10))
            ScaledText(label: "LargeTitle", size: scaledLargeTitle)
            ScaledText(label: "Title", size: scaledTitle)
            ScaledText(label: "Headline", size: scaledHeadline)
            ScaledText(label: "Subheadline", size: scaledSubheadline)
            ScaledText(label: "Body", size: scaledBody)
            ScaledText(label: "Callout", size: scaledCallout)
            ScaledText(label: "Caption", size: scaledCaption)
            ScaledText(label: "Footnote", size: scaledFootnote)
            ScaledText(label: "Not Specified", size: scaledNothing)
        }
    }
}

struct ScaledText: View {
    var label: String
    var size: CGFloat
    var body: some View {
        Text("Scaled by \(label) to \(size, specifier: "%.2f")")
            .font(Font.system(size: size))
    }
}

struct TextLabelsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TextLabelsView()
            .environment(\.sizeCategory, ContentSizeCategory.accessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge)
        TextLabelsView()
            .environment(\.sizeCategory, ContentSizeCategory.small)
    }
}
```

With this you can see the different scaling factors for the different Font.TextStyle|s.